# new to Ubuntu and trying to remove programs getting an error

Tags: software-installation

```
Authentication is required to remove software
Incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)
```

Guys... I'm the new kid on the block and picked up this laptop with Ubuntu 18 on it. It works great, but has SW on it that I don't need and want to remove. When I try to remove the SW, I get the above error message.

How do I correct this? Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the results of `ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1` ?

Comment: owner@owner-Vostro-3550:~$ ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 Mar 27 08:57 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
owner@owner-Vostro-3550:~$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is right. I'm not sure why and how it happened, but the `/usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1` file is no longer setuid root. To make it setuid root, open the terminal and run:

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

The terminal output in your comments looks OK. Test if the command was successful:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 mmm dd tt:tt /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
```

where `mmm` can be any month, `dd` can be any day, and `tt:tt` can be any time.

Comment: Ok. Did that and it asked for Owners password so I put in what I thought it was and hit enter. Then terminal showed $

Comment: Correction: the terminal shiwed:

Comment: Owner@owner-Vostro-3550:-$

Comment: terminal reply is: -rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 14328 mmm dd tt:tt /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1

Comment: Does this solve the `Authentication is required to remove software
Incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 (needs to be setuid root)` error message that you got when you tried to remove software?

Comment: Yes sir!! That did it!! Your awesome Karel!! Thanks very much!

Comment: Done Karel!! Thanks much again. ✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓✓ 